# Calling an addon's Operator from Python - wm_operator_invoke: invalid operator call

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I seem to get two different behaviours from the Blender interface and from external scripts when trying to invoke my addon's operator function `object.myaddonoperator()`

```
import bpy

class MyAddonOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.myaddonoperator"
    bl_label = "My Addon"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return context.mode == 'OBJECT'

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        do_stuff()

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

From the console within Blender, calling `bpy.ops.object.myaddonoperator('INVOKE_DEFAULT')` works just fine, but when using an external script with `blender -b -P my_script.py`, calling the same results in `wm_operator_invoke: invalid operator call 'OBJECT_OT_myaddonoperator'`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

To use the plugin in the way intended, `execute()` needs to be used instead of `invoke()`. The execute method can still use the invoke code by calling it with an event of `None`:

```
class MyAddonOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.myaddonoperator"
    bl_label = "My Addon"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return context.mode == 'OBJECT'

    def execute(self, context):
        return self.invoke(context, None)    

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        do_stuff()

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Now the addon can be called with `bpy.ops.object.myaddonoperator('EXEC_DEFAULT')`

Answer (score 0):

@Chris Watts
Doesn't seem to be valid in 2022 (or am I wrong?).
Created this small addon and calling `bpy.ops.object.myaddonoperator('EXEC_DEFAULT')` returns an error:

> AttributeError: Calling operator "bpy.ops.object.myaddonoperator" error, could not be found

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Call Operator from console",
    "category": "Object",
}

import bpy

class ABC_OT_MyAddonOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.myaddonoperator"
    bl_label = "My Addon"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return context.mode == 'OBJECT'

    def execute(self, context):
        return self.invoke(context, None)    

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        print('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ABC_OT_MyAddonOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ABC_OT_MyAddonOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

*P.S. not sure if this should have been an alternate post or a comment below your code sample.*